# Meta-Connect Wall #2

Tags: connect-wall

Sort the sixteen terms into four categories. The four categories are joined by a common thread, with that being the solution. I think this one will play hard, so good luck!

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SQUASH | ARTICHOKE | EARLY SPRING | CUPID'S ARROW |
| PUPPY LOVE | EMPATHIZES | ACQUITTAL | CROWD SURGE |
| BLACK HISTORY | YOUR STOP | PROM NIGHT | DEVASTATE |
| WASHINGTON | 5PM | ROMAINE | AMETHYST |

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the common theme between the four categories here is:

> **Valentine's Day** (which is today, of course - February 14th...).

The categories should be:

> **Group 1: A time to 'get off'**
>  5PM (from work), ACQUITTAL (from a criminal charge), PROM NIGHT (with your date), YOUR STOP (when using public transport).
>
>  **Group 2: Words meaning 'Crush'**
>  CROWD SURGE (a physical crush in a public place like a stadium), DEVASTATE (crush, emotionally), PUPPY LOVE (a romantic crush, typically when young), SQUASH (crush physically).
>
>  **Group 3: Things that have a *heart***
>  [ARTICHOKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artichoke#Description), CUPID'S ARROW (traditionally depicted as having a heart-shaped head), EMPATHIZES (i.e. cares, or 'has a heart'), ROMAINE (the [lettuce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romaine_lettuce), sold in 'hearts').
>
>  **Group 4: Connected with the month of February**
>  AMETHYST (February's [birthstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amethyst#Other_cultural_associations)), BLACK HISTORY (February is [Black History Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_History_Month)), EARLY SPRING (the first bulbs and shoots begin to show in February, in the Northern Hemisphere), WASHINGTON (George Washington's [birthday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidents%27_Day)).

Considering all of these together...

> Valentine's Day is a time to '*get off*' (though some might phrase that more tenderly...) with a partner or a *crush*, is associated with *hearts*, and is celebrated in *February*.